# Shared Access 2003 database performance

Tags: database, ms-access, shared, ms-access-2003, database-performance

I've to create a Access 2003 database and share it among 100 users, users won't be doing any modifications, only viewing several reports that are generated daily (and once) using a scheduled task on the host machine.

Would a simultaneous 100 users break the performances down in that context?

What would you advise me regarding this workflow?

Exclude:

- Using a database server (sqlserver,...etc) is out of topic
- I've already thought about outputting the reports into static html, but now I want to first evaluate the sharing of the whole database (because filtering capability might be needed)
- I'd like to avoid replication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the word "host". Remember, Access is not a true client-server engine: it merely provides access to the data; consumers pull the data down to their local machines, where their local Access runtime or local Access development version executes the query against the downloaded data.  Entire "freight trains" of data can come down across the wire to the desktop.

Some years ago we had a large database that the customer wanted in Access (eventually moved it to Oracle). Some queries would eat up 90%-100% of available LAN bandwidth for 15-30 seconds, during which time other write operations to completely different databases on the LAN would time-out, and data corruption would result.

So the main concern of your scenario would be the effects of possibly severe degradation on other applications. It will depend on the size of your database and the nature of your queries behind the reports.

I'd recommend "canning" the reports if you can, so that each running of a report does not invoke the query that instantiates the data behind it.

EDIT: An alternative, if one is necessary, would be to have a web server *running on the same machine as the Access "host"* executing the queries, and serving the end-result reports out to the consumers' browsers as HTML.  This would reduce bandwidth consumption.  The LAN becomes "the cloud".

Comment: Hi Tim. Actually I used the word **host** to refer to the central machine that is sharing the database access. I've also decided to, on a daily basis, right after collecting new data, to store the report query result into a table rather than actually creating the reports. Then when the users will run a report it will be built on top of this table so the only executed query will be the filtering one (based on user input); this query is simple as hell it looks like:
SELECT * FROM T Where X = B and A = Z AND (R between 10 AND 1010100) AND SS > TT... etc. What do you think ?

Comment: If you're inserting the results of the query into a new table, so that reports are based on a small static subset of your data, then you're "canning" them in the way I suggested. That's good. But the apparent simplicity of the SQL statement isn't important; it is the number of bytes that have to come across the wire. Bandwidth consumption will depend on the size of those static tables that stand behind the reports.

Comment: I see, then I'll try to figure out what the network load would look like and try to set this up. Man thank you very much, very good points !

Comment: The statement about Access pulling large amounts of data down the wire is misleading, if not outright false. A full data table is not pulled unless you've got no indexes or write bad SQL that requires a full table scan (e.g., sorting on an expression without as WHERE clause). If your queries were eating up 90% of LAN bandwidth, then they were REALLY badly written, or your database schema was extremely poor. With a server database, Jet/ACE sometimes guesses wrong, in which case you move selection logic server-side (either VIEWS or SPROCs). But what you describe is not common.

Comment: 100 read-only reporting users should never be much of a problem with Access, unless your SQL is extremely complex or you've made design errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you give each user their own copy of the front end and linked to the data source then you might get away with 100 users if the network is up to scratch. I have about 100 users mostly read only on an access DB but they are not all using it at the same time

You can automate the front end installation using the excellent autoFE updater 
www.autofeupdater.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I even though can't use any 3rd party software so autofe is out of scope.

Comment: Before I found out about AutoFE I "rolled" my own using a small bootstrap access database that sits on the network drive. When the users open this DB it checks to see if they have the real front end on their computer, if they dont it installs and launches it. If they do it checks to see if it is up to date and updates it if the version number is less than the one on the server. All of this using just access databases, no 3rd party tools

Comment: Yeah goot point though, I in fact don't know if I'll really need this for now, because I'll do one version of it then deploy it and that's it, but I'll keep that in mind. Thank you very much